# Releasing an NSString that I am done with causes a crash

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, memory-management, nsstring

Note the commented-out `[printvolfirst release];` line below. If I un-comment it, the program crashes. I can't figure out why. The `printvolfirst` variable is not used anywhere else except in the lines of code you see here. After it is assigned to `printvol` I'm done with it. So why not release it?

```
vol = vol / 1000000;
NSNumberFormatter * format = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init] ;
[format setPositiveFormat:@"#.#"];
NSString * printvolfirst = [[NSString alloc]init];
printvolfirst = [format stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:vol]];

NSString * printvol = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat: @"%@M", printvolfirst];

self.Pop.vol.text = printvol;
[printvol release];
//[printvolfirst release];
[format  release];
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`stringFromNumber:` autoreleases the returned object. If you release it again, it's released after it has been deallocated.

In fact, you don't even need this code:

```
NSString*printvolfirst=[[NSString alloc]init];
```

---

You can turn on 'Run Static Analyser' in the build settings to get warned about such things.

Comment: interesting. i thought i "own" this variable if I use alloc/init directly, and I own it until i release it. not true? how would I do this if I wanted to retain printvolfirst, not autorelease it?

Comment: You can retain it by sending it the `retain` message. It is true that when you `alloc`, `retain` or `copy` an object, you own it. But what you are doing is allocing an object, then setting it to a new object immediately introducing a memory leak. If you enable the analyser it should exactly tell you what you've done wrong. :)

Comment: @andrewjs: The key thing you're missing is that you don't own *variables* — you own *objects*. You initially assign the variable an empty string (which you do own), then you throw that string away and assign the result of `stringFromNumber:` (which you do not own). Those are two different objects. Storing them in the same variable doesn't change their memory management requirements.

Answer (score 1):

You are deallocating an `autorelease`d string. Although you are doing `NSString*printvolfirst=[[NSString alloc]init];`, you are losing the reference to that object when you do `printvolfirst=[format stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:vol]];` where you assign an autoreleased object to `printvolfirst`. In the process, you have also created a memory leak. You don't have to release it.